# How I print specific values from a multidimensional array with numpy?

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

I have a multidimensional np.array like: [[2, 55, 62], [3, 56,63], [4, 57, 64], ...].

I'm pretending to print only the values greater than 2 at the firt column, returnig a print like: [[3, 56,63], [4, 57, 64], ...]

How can I get it?

Comment: `arr[mask]` where `mask=arr[:,0]>2`

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to select just the values you want to print.

Short answer:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2,3],[3,2,1]])
print(a[a>2])
```

What's going on?

Well, first, `a>2` return a boolean mask telling if condition is met for each position of the array. This is a numpy array with exactly the same shape than `a`, but with `dtype=bool`.

Then, this mask is used to select only values where the mask's value is `True`, which are also those hat meet your condition.

Finally, you just print them.

Step by step, you can write as follows:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2,3],[3,2,1]])
print(a.shape)  # output is (2, 3)
mask = a > 2
print(mask.shape)  # output is (2, 3)
print(mask.dtype)  # output is book
print(mask)  # here you can see True only for those positions where condition is met
print(a[mask])
```